# Copy Sqlite db from assets to internal storage(Android+cordova)

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I was trying copy databases from assets to internal storage, yet I used java android("copy database") and cordova("call & read & wirte database"). Moreover, everything in emulator was right and I could retrieve data of table in database but when I run of cell phone or tablet didn't recognize table and retrieve data however I am sure that copy db was done because I took to export on sdcard before call database. I suppose need to permission and I don't have clue about this problem.

Features:
- cordova 3.4.0.js
-cordova-2.7.0.jar

There are two files:

/data/data/[Package name]/app_webview/databases/Databases.db

/data/data/[Package name]/app_webview/databases/file__0/1

**In MainActivity.java**

```
private String filepath = "webview";

ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

File CheckDirectory;
CheckDirectory = new File("/data/data/com.example.sample/app_webview/databases/");
CheckDirectory.mkdirs();

CheckDirectory = new File("/data/data/com.example.sample/app_webview/databases/file__0/");
CheckDirectory.mkdirs();

this.copy("Databases.db", "/data/data/com.example.sample/app_webview/databases/");
            //this.copy("Databases.db-journal", "/data/data/com.example.sample/app_webview/databases/");
            this.copy("1", "/data/data/com.example.sample/app_webview/databases/file__0/");

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

**In index.html**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", successCB, false);

function successCB() {
       var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Saeed", 200000);
       db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);

    }
function queryDB(tx) {
       tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TEST', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }
```

Comment: I think we need to see some code.

Comment: how can I add codes in comment?I used MainActivity.java and index.html files

Comment: Just do an edit to your question and add the code.